# 2.79 Baking normal maps with procedural texture doesn't work

Tags: texturing, uv, baking, normal-map, procedural

(Blender v. 2.79)
Hey Blender community! 
I am not completely new to Blender but not really experienced either. I wanted to model a container and use a procedural material to get some rusty spots on the container. But everytime i try to bake my normal map it gets weird and displays a darker version, not really how it's supposed to look.
I used the method desribed in another thread and baked out the color of the emission. That way (at least in that thread) i should get the color of the normal map and then be able to plug that into a normal map. But everytime I do that i get a weird texture that doesn't look how it should.
Down below I'll post some screenshots of how it looks.

[image]
Here is the general setup. I just took the normal map inputs and fed them into emission and into the output and then baked out the emission. End result looks weird.

[image]
If I plug in that normal map it looks very weird and not how its supposed to be.

[image]
The whole normal setup from my procedural texture.

[image]
How it's supposed to look (This is with the procedural material)

[image]
How it looks with the baked out normal map

I do not know what I'm doing wrong. Maybe you guys can help me out.

I even tried to just bake out the normal map on a flat plane but even that did not work.
[image]
Plane with procedural material

[image]
How its supposed to look (procedural material)

[image]
With normal map: It just adds a darker color to it, even though its set to non-color data.

Before you ask: Yes, both models (plane and container) are UV unwrapped. I wanted to test the plane to see if i made something wrong in the UVs but even the plane doesn't display the normal map properly.

Comment: Have a look at [this article](http://digicreatures.net/articles/cycles-normal-baking.html).. I think it may contain an explanation, and a solution, to your problem, (which shouldn't persist beyond 2.80)

Comment: Okay, I'll check it out later. Thanks for the information :)